# Issue with running test from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, python-unittest

I am working with Python 2.7.9 in PyCharm

This is my project structure:

```
/JUAN
    /framework
        /config
        /page_objects
            /locators
        /tests
            /log_in
        /wrapper
```

In the `locators` folder I stored in JSON files the locators of each page object. In the `log_in` folder I have a test. 
This is the content of the test:

```
""" Test to verify the Sign In page."""

import unittest
from framework.page_objects.sign_in_page import SignInPage
from framework.tests.selenium_test_base import SeleniumTestBase

class TestVerifyPage(SeleniumTestBase):

    def test_verify_page(self):
        sign_inPage = SignInPage()
        sign_inPage.verify_elements_on_page()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

If I run it doing right-click and selecting *Run* the test passes. But if I try to execute it through the terminal I am getting the following issue:

Line executed:

```
C:\JUAN\framework>python -m unittest ./tests/log_in/test_verify_page.py test_verify_page()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ValueError: Empty module name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find 2 solutions:

Solution 1:

What I did was deleted the `framework` folder.

Also the line to execute in the terminal is:

```
python -m unittest test_verify_page
```

Solution 2:

If you want to leave the module structure, you need to create a `setup.py` file in the root directory

`setup.py` content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='SxD',
      packages=['framework','config', 'page_objects','tests', 'wrapper'])
```

Then in the root directoy execute this command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

A `build` folder is created with modules references.